# Lambda Expression with OR expression

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have `DB.Select` statement from a ServiceStack call to a list that works fine. It goes as follows:

```
List<MyTable> MyData = new List<MyTable>();
MyData = Db.Select<MyClass>().Where(n => n.thisfield.StartsWith("d1")).ToList();
```

I simply want to be able to use the same statement with a AND or a OR so it would look something kind of like...

```
List<MyTable> MyData = new List<MyTable>();
MyData = Db.Select<MyClass>().Where((n => n.thisfield.StartsWith("d1")).ToList()  
                                       || n.thisfield.StartsWith("d2")).ToList());
```

But I am having syntax problems, my goal is to use check if this field starts with `"D1"` or `"D2"` within the same statement. Is that possible?

Comment: `StartsWith` returns a `bool`, and you are trying `ToList` on it. Remove the  `ToList` from inside the expression and just add it after closing bracket of `Where` clause.

Comment: `)).ToList()` before `||` makes no sense

Comment: `MyData = Db.Select<MyClass>().Where(n => n.thisfield.StartsWith("d1")  || n.thisfield.StartsWith("d2")).ToList();`

Comment: Note: The `.ToList()` is unnecessary in OrmLite since `Select<T>` always returns a `List<T>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
List<MyClass> myData = Db.Select<MyClass>(q => 
   q.Where(n => n.thisfield.StartsWith("d1") || n.thisfield.StartsWith("d2"));
```

Comment: @JasonR. Based on the examples at https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite it seems like you probably want to put your criterion expression inside the `Select()` call to ensure that you're filtering at the database level. If you do that, as @mythz mentioned, the `ToList()` shouldn't be necessary.